# R - Apriori function error

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, apriori, arules

I'm currently having problems with the apriori function. The thing is I have a csv with data like the following:

```
Desc,Cantidad,Valor,Fecha,Lugar,UUID
DESCUENTO,1,-3405,2014-10-04T14:02:57,53100,7F74AFC0-FC28-4105-89A5-CD99416B50C7
DESCUENTO,1,-3405,2014-10-04T14:02:57,53100,7F74AFC0-FC28-4105-89A5-CD99416B50C7
DESCUENTO,1,-170,2014-09-05T15:10:24,83000,7F0C7F0B-BCFC-4FCA-8740-B36AE9932869
Descuento de TYK Dia,1,-156,2014-06-19T16:52:27,86280,1E08E51E-213A-4EE0-8FE9-492E677FF0C9
Descuento de TYK Dia,1,-139,2014-04-25T10:52:44,86280,AB802E63-2D0D-4B47-AB70-DDE007929F9F
DESCUENTO,1,-63,2014-07-04T13:53:10,83000,5B1F12BB-71DE-4734-A774-8D377757A880
REDONDEO,1,-1,2014-03-29T10:50:59,0,5B241EFA-6654-46EA-B47A-3CB76C5EA923
DESCUENTO,1,-1,2014-10-04T14:02:57,53100,7F74AFC0-FC28-4105-89A5-CD99416B50C7
DESCUENTO,1,-1,2014-10-04T14:02:57,53100,7F74AFC0-FC28-4105-89A5-CD99416B50C7
LAVADO,1,0,2014-05-27T18:18:11,44500,e5d540d6-0f98-4993-ec09-56887cd4a27d
TUA,1,0,2014-09-29T10:20:31,6500,1d8ada06-a8a1-4bd8-9356-851b5da28108
Transportación Aerea,1,0,2014-10-03T10:41:09,6500,5fc3925a-d08a-4cdc-be7e-ca02bd488d5b
OBSEQUIO LAVADO DE CARROCERIA,1,0,2014-04-07T13:45:55,91800,8148ab07-5804-4b2b-b37c-5323b394907a
Arroz Al Azafran Combos A,1,0,2014-08-19T11:50:34,11520,f09c23e6-dc60-4aaf-a1b8-1506d38f3585
Frijoles Charros A,1,0,2014-08-19T11:50:34,11520,f09c23e6-dc60-4aaf-a1b8-1506d38f3585
Pepsi Ch A,1,0,2014-08-19T11:50:34,11520,f09c23e6-dc60-4aaf-a1b8-1506d38f3585
FECHA DE CONSUMO 18/07/2014,1,0,2014-07-19T18:01:45,6060,0f0465aa-a75b-4f95-8e3b-43c13452cafb
CAMBIO DE ACEITE DE MOTOR,1,0,2014-02-01T11:18:53,39890,5BDF0742-CDF5-4F6B-9937-DF1CB00274ED
CAMBIO DE FILTRO DE ACEITE,1,0,2014-02-01T11:18:53,39890,5BDF0742-CDF5-4F6B-9937-DF1CB00274ED
```

Whole CSV (https://github.com/antonio1695/BaseX/blob/master/facturas1.csv)
To download the file just click on find file and then you will see the file. 
So what I did was:

```
> df1 <- read.csv("facturas1.csv")
> rules <- apriori(df1,parameter=list(support=0.01,confidence=0.5))
Error in asMethod(object) : 
column(s) 3 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
```

Nevertheless, the problem is that the columns are discrete already and if I change the data in order for it to have column 3 in the place of column 2 and viceversa. It still says that that column 3 is not logical or a factor when it should say it about column 2 instead. Thanks!

Comment: It seems `apriori` only takes factors or logical as input

Comment: Yeah I got that, the thing is when I swap the columns, the non logical or non factor input should be column 2. Nevertheless the error still said the problem was with column 3. If my input in column 3 would've not been logical or a factor input the next mistake would've said that the error was in column 2...    @HubertL

Comment: I got `column(s) 2, 3, 5 not logical or a factor`

Comment: If it helps, heres the whole csv: https://github.com/antonio1695/BaseX/blob/master/facturas1.csv

If you have a different error, saying 3 columns are not logical or a factor you can always delete column 5 and use excel to make columns 2 and 3 discrete. That should make you see the same thing as I do. @HubertL

Comment: What would you expect the result from `apriori`to look like?

Comment: It should give me something like this:
`Apriori
Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen
        0.5    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE    0.01      1
 maxlen target   ext
     10  rules FALSE
Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE
Absolute minimum support count: 101`

That would mean it worked.

@lukeA

Comment: I mean in terms of rules. I cannot see how the csv is a transactional data set.

Comment: Well I don;t know which rules i will find, that's the point of it...

Probably an easy one would be like {descripcion = Consumo} => {Cantidad =1}
@lukeA

Comment: @HubertL Any ideas so far?

Comment: I don't know what the columns are about, but maybe try `library(arules);download.file("https://github.com/antonio1695/BaseX/raw/master/facturas1.csv", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"));df1 <- read.csv(tf);rules <- apriori(transform(df1, Valor=as.factor(Valor)),parameter=list(support=0.01,confidence=0.5))`. As `?transactions` tells you, _"signature(from = "data.frame", to = "transactions"); recodes the data frame containing only categorical variables (factors) ... into a binary transaction data set...."_. So, make it all factors or create a binary matrix.

Comment: You can use `as.factor()` to make categorical variables

Comment: I already tried **as.factor()** but it says my matrix isn't 0-1 logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that the **apriori** function must take intervals in order for it to work properly, so when you use **discretize** you must add the parameter "categories" to select how many intervals you want. It isn't possible for it not to take intervals. I'll post the code here:

I decided to take 20 intervals which are all depending on how often the value in the interval is repeated.

```
df$Valor <- discretize(df$Valor, method="frequency",categories = 20)
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

```
 library(arules)
 df1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antonio1695/BaseX/master/facturas1.csv")
 trans <- as(df1, "transactions")
  Error in asMethod(object) : 
  column(s) 3 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
```

Let's look at the data frame:

```
str(df1)
 'data.frame':  10510 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Desc    : Factor w/ 3927 levels "0","00000215R0 - LIQUIDO DE FRENOS",..: 1490 1490 1490 1491 1491 1490 3209 1490 1490 2238 ...
 $ Cantidad: Factor w/ 85 levels "","1","-1","10",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Valor   : int  -3405 -3405 -170 -156 -139 -63 -1 -1 -1 0 ...
 $ Fecha   : Factor w/ 4054 levels "1294","2014-01-06T11:10:21",..: 4041 4041 3443 1794 596 2125 241 4041 4041 1215 ...
 $ Lugar   : Factor w/ 982 levels "","0","1000",..: 487 487 802 848 848 802 2 487 487 373 ...
 $ UUID    : Factor w/ 4056 levels "0019A60D-78F8-E341-8D3E-9786201FE017",..: 1988 1988 1979 456 2711 1423 1424 1988 1988 3658 ...
```

Valor is a number (int) and needs to be discretized! For example with `discretize():`

```
df1$Valor <- discretize(df1$Valor)
head(df1$Valor)
 [1] [-3405, 2400) [-3405, 2400) [-3405, 2400) [-3405, 2400) [-3405, 2400)
 [6] [-3405, 2400)
 Levels: [-3405, 2400) [ 2400, 8204) [ 8204,14009]
```

Now you can create transactions and applt APRIORI:

```
trans <- as(df1, "transactions")
rules <- apriori(trans,parameter=list(support=0.01,confidence=0.5))
rules
 set of 84 rules
```

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized it didn't work since I did that but it changes my data and makes the values an interval when I see the table you every item has a value set as [-3405,2400] making my association rules useless. I don't know if you saw this.

Comment: It gives me rules like this one:
  ` {Valor=[-3405, 2400)}  => {Cantidad=[  -1,1627)} 0.9923882 0.9996166  0.9999972 2    `

Which clearly isn't very helpful.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot, gave you +1, and I was able to get the answer!